# wordpress site from http to https, category pages keep load js and css resources files from http instead https while other pages are all good

Tags: php, css, wordpress, themes

I'm heading into an odd issue about wordpress.
  I've moved wordpress site from http to https, category pages keep load js and css resources files from http instead https while other pages are all good. No category template added and no is_category() handler in functions.php. Is anyone aware of what is the issue?

[image]

Comment: Any warnings or errors in the console?

Comment: yes, there are.

`Mixed Content: The page at 'https://staging-1.ponoko.com/blog/category/promotional-products/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'http://staging-1.ponoko.com/blog/wp-content/plugins/audio-player/assets/audio-player.js?ver=20100105100911'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
staging-1.ponoko.com/:202 Uncaught ReferenceError: AudioPlayer is not defined
(index):203`

Comment: A simple HSTS (`Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000"`) + HTTP2HTTPS redirect (`RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
`) would patch the issue while you find where it comes from (Apache htaccess examples).

Answer (score 0):

Under WordPress->Settings->General you will find WordPress Address (URL) and Site Address (URL) update these to start with https://.

If the issue is not resolved by doing the above maybe look at the header and footer of your template to check you are not pulling in external or internal files using http:// if you are remove the http: and just leave //

Let me know if this helps resolve the issue, if it doesn't I have a few other ideas.

Comment: other pages are good and using https://, but just the category pages like https://staging-1.ponoko.com/blog/category/promotional-prod‌​ucts/ will request some http:// resources

Comment: I'm getting a 404 from this page.

Comment: Have you tried any plugins to fix this issue? https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/wp-force-ssl/

Answer (score 0):

Find the place where

`http://staging-1.ponoko.com/blog/wp-content/plugins/audio-p‌​layer/assets/audio-p‌​layer.js?ver=2010010‌​5100911`

are included and change it into an https Request:

`https://staging-1.ponoko.com/blog/wp-content/plugins/audio-p‌​layer/assets/audio-p‌​layer.js?ver=2010010‌​5100911`